# How can I block a computer from my linksys router by IP or MAC address?

Tags: router, ip, blocking, mac-address

How can I block a computer (not on Wireless) from my linksys router by IP or MAC Address?  I am using a linksys WAG200G.

Comment: Wait, I read this as it isn't wireless... meaning that the host is wired.  Is the computer actually connecting by wireless, but the option isn't found under the "Wireless" tab?

Comment: here's a simple option... if it's wired disconnect it!  If it's wireless then follow Cypher's suggestion.  Either way you need to clarify what's going on.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, Linksys routers do not support this for the wired interfaces.  They assume that if you have physical access than the node is supposed to be able to connect.  You might have some luck with one of the open source replacement firmwares (tomato, openwrt, dd-wrt, etc.) and firewalling the host via iptables.

Comment: What is tomato ? do you mean I can remove orginal control panel of my linksys (192.168.1.1) and put another kind of control panel ?

Comment: Yes, precisely.  Tomato is available here: http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato  You will need to do a bit of research on the various firmwares to see what is compatible with your router.  Be careful -- this can effectively ruin the router if the flashing process doesn't go well.